# Give <a> element autofocus

Tags: javascript, html

With the following code I try to give an a element autofocus when the page is loaded.

```
<a href="/{{setting}}" id="next" class="button big active">Next vocabulary</a>
<script>
    document.getElementbyId("next").focus();
</script>
```

Whilst this works fine with input fields it doesn't work with that a element. Can anybody explain me while?

Regards

Comment: ...because there's nothing to type in an `a` element?

Comment: Why would you focus an a element ? I don't think that there an real .focus() for a. Maybe highlight it with css ?

Comment: Because it is an interactive control. Pressing `tab` will go to the next one in sequence. Pressing `enter` will follow the link.

Comment: Which browser you are testing on? Works on my chrome and ie. I assume `getElementbyId` is a typo not done in your code, if I'm wrong change that to `getElementById`.

Comment: Just to make it clearer: Autofocusing a link makes a lot of sense for people using assistive software. For example, when a modal window popups up with a list of links, it makes sense to focus the first link so that the user can easily navigate through the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you typed `getElementById` wrong, it should be an uppercase 'B'.

```
<a href="/{{setting}}" id="next" class="button big active">Next vocabulary</a>
<script>
    document.getElementById("next").focus();
</script>
```

This should now work!

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed the uppercase 'B' that caused the problem. 

I wasn't fully aware of that.

Since some people asked why I want to give an a element the focus. In my implementation a next button is realised with the a element.

Regards