# Autofocus on <a> element without JavaScript

Tags: html

Is there a way to autofocus on an `<a>` element without JavaScript? I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566031/give-a-element-autofocus) that includes JS, but I'd like to minimize the amount of JS in my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide an `id` attribute to the `<a>` and update the link to the page with `#{id}`.

`<a id="focus">foo</a>`

And update the link to the page with the focused element to `http://www.example.com/mypage#focus`

If you have a link on the same page (on a navigation section, for example) you can just use

`<a href="#focus">foo</a>` to jump to the anchor.