# Scroll to specified part of page when clicking top navigation link in Blazor

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor

How can I make a simple "jump to" part of already loaded page in Blazor? Like this in HTML:

```
<a href="#contact">Contact us</a>
...
<section id="contact">
```

Ideally I also want to have it smooth scroll down to this section. Thought I would try to solve this with CSS, but maybe not possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autofocus on <a> element without JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55055291/autofocus-on-a-element-without-javascript)

Comment: @BabakNaffas that technique generally doesn't work with SPA apps like Blazor.

Comment: Thanks @KirkWoll. Good to know.

Answer (score 23):

I've solved this by using a `button` and then writing some inline Javascript in the markup.  You can generalize this to a Blazor component for bonus points!

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('contact').scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'})">Contact us</button>
...
<section id="contact">
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost solved it for me! See my solution to add on to this one.

Comment: I don't see what's different from your answer, but glad it got you on the right track

Answer (score 6):

What you need is the hashed routes features of Blazor. But, alas, no such features do exist yet. I'd suggest you use JSIterop to perform this task: Create a JavaScript that performs the navigation, and pass it an ElementRef object.

Hope this helps...

Edit: The following is an adaptation of the best workaround solution I've found in Github...

Ordinarily, when you click the link to contact, you get redirected to the route http://localhost:5000/mypage#contact, but will be at the top of the page. The fragment of the route is not used for selection of a specific HTML element.

The current workaround is to write explicit code that interprets the URL. In the example above, we could use a little bit of JavaScript and then call that from our Blazor code:

mypage.cshtml:

```
         @page "/mypage"
    @inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Services.IUriHelper UriHelper

    <nav>

        <a href="#contact">contact</a>


    </nav>


    <section>
        <h2 id="contact">contact</h2>

    </section>


@functions {
    protected override void OnInit()
    {
        NavigateToElement();
        UriHelper.OnLocationChanged += OnLocationChanges;
    }

    private void OnLocationChanges(object sender, string location) => NavigateToElement();

    private void NavigateToElement()
    {
        var url = UriHelper.GetAbsoluteUri();
        var fragment = new Uri(url).Fragment;

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(fragment))
        {
            return;
        }

        var elementId = fragment.StartsWith("#") ? fragment.Substring(1) : fragment;

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(elementId))
        {
            return;
        }

        ScrollToElementId(elementId);
    }

    private static bool ScrollToElementId(string elementId)
    {
        return JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<bool>("scrollToElementId", elementId).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<script>
        window.scrollToElementId = (elementId) => {
            console.info('scrolling to element', elementId);
            var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
            if(!element)
            {
                console.warn('element was not found', elementId);
                return false;
            }
            element.scrollIntoView();
            return true;
        }
</script>
```

Note: If you're using Blazor version .9.0, you should inject the IJSRuntime
      Please, let me know if this solution works for you...

Comment: Nice Issac, remember `JSRuntime.Current` is not more supported. Now ( >= 0.9.0 ) you must instantiate `JSRuntime` via DI. :)

Comment: Tried it out. Microsoft Edge scrolls to correct area, then no reaction when I click the other links in navigation. Chrome and Firefox doesn't scroll at all, and nothing happens when clicking the other links in navigation. Really appreciate the effort though! Would be nice if someone else tried it, so I know if there is something else in my site that is causing problems. Note, I am running Blazor 0.7.0

Comment: I have tried this now in Blazor 0.9.0. With the default project that is created when you make a new Blazor project. Just to see if there was something strange in my site that was preventing it from working. Did not work there either. In the github page where you found it I see that he has commented "The proposed workaround does not work, since the browser crashes and is only for illustration." So we'll just have to wait I guess.

Answer (score 6):

You can use 2 Nuget packages to solve this:

1. [Scroll JS](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components/blob/master/.github/docs/JsInterop.md#scroll-js-see-demo-app) which is part of [JsInterop Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.Common.JsInterop/). This has many feature see the docs but main part is `IScrollHandler` which is an injectable service. You can try it out with the [demo app](https://blazorextensions.z6.web.core.windows.net/jsinterop#scroll-js). You can see the `scrollIntoView()` and other JS functions wrapped, smooth scroll available. So much simpler to use JS scroll support...
2. Second option is to use "[Parmalinks](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components/blob/master/.github/docs/PermaLink.md)" in the URL you have "#". [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.PermaLink) available here. It is what you requested. Basically it is using `<a>` tags but you don't have to bother with it (note even demo app has # URLs). Also renders "link" component with clickable icon and navigate/copy actions. Currenlty smooth scroll is not available but can be requested. You can try it out with the [demo app](https://blazorextensions.z6.web.core.windows.net/permalink#standard-a-tag).
   [image: Modal demo]

Answer (score 5):

I used Arron Hudon's answer and it still didn't work. However, after playing around I realized it wouldn't work with an anchor element: `<a id='star_wars'>Place to jump to</a>`. Apparently Blazor and other spa frameworks have issues jumping to **anchors** on the same page. To get around that I had to use a paragraph element instead (section would work too): `<p id='star_wars'>Some paragraph<p>`.

Example using bootstrap:

```
<button class="btn btn-link" onclick="document.getElementById('star_wars').scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'})">Star Wars</button>

... lots of other text

<p id="star_wars">Star Wars is an American epic...</p>
```

Notice I used bootstrap's `btn-link` class to make the button look like a hyperlink.

Answer (score 3):

The same answer as the Issac's answer, but need to change some code.

I found the main problem is that you need it to be async. @johajan

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

...

```
@functions {
protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
{
    await base.OnInitAsync();
    //NavigateToElement();
    UriHelper.OnLocationChanged += OnLocationChanges;
}

private async Task OnLocationChanges(object sender, string location) => await NavigateToElement();

private async Task NavigateToElement()
{
    var url = UriHelper.GetAbsoluteUri();
    var fragment = new Uri(url).Fragment;

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(fragment))
    {
        return;
    }

    var elementId = fragment.StartsWith("#") ? fragment.Substring(1) : fragment;

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(elementId))
    {
        return;
    }

    await ScrollToElementId(elementId);
}

private Task<bool> ScrollToElementId(string elementId)
{
    return JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("scrollToElementId", elementId);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

The most easy way to do that is the following:

1. Add a javascript file into you project.
2. Inside of it, add this function :

   ```
   function ScrollTo(elementId) {
   var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
   element.scrollIntoView({
   behavior: 'smooth'
   });}
   ```
3. Add the script reference into your index.html :

   ```
   <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
   ```
4. Back to you your page, on your link add an onclick event :

   ```
   <a @onclick="(async() => await ScrolltoContact())">Contact</a>
   ```
5. Inject IJSRuntime :

   ```
     @inject IJSRuntime javaScript;
   ```
6. Create the method to call the javascript function :

   ```
   async Task ScrolltoContact()
   {
       await javaScript.InvokeVoidAsync("ScrollTo", "Contact");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make @Aaron Hudon's Answer a little more perfect I did the bellow:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('contact').scrollIntoView({behavior:'smooth'})">Contact us</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to add my solution if that is okay.  The following worked for me:

```
 function Navigate(location) {
    let elem = document.getElementById(location); // get element to be scrolled to
    let header = document.querySelector("header"); // get header element
    header.style.display = "none"; // hide header element (toggle navbar - is there a better way to do this?)
    elem.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' }); // scrollIntoView function
}

    <nav hidden="@Show" class="@NavBarClass">
    @{
        string Home = "Home";
        string About = "About";
        string Blog = "Blog";
        string Contact = "Contact";
    }
    <ul>
        <li><NavLink href="#Home" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" @onclick="(() => Navigate(Home))">Home</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink href="#About" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" @onclick="(() => Navigate(About))">About</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink href="#Blog" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" @onclick="(() => Navigate(Blog))">Blog</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink href="#Contact" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" @onclick="(() => Navigate(Contact))">Contact</NavLink></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


private async Task Navigate(string location)
{
    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("HideMenu", location);
    await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("Navigate", location);
}
```

Spent the past week working on this and I'm over the moon about getting it working just now!!

Douglas

Comment: It's not recommended to put JS code on razor markup.

Comment: No, it is in an external JS file.  The text editor on Stack wouldn't let me put titles above code blocks without saying it is invalid.