# Scroll click not working with NavigationManager.NavigateTo, and I can't use href because I need forceLoad functionality

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor Server web app; .NET 5.

I am running into frustrations related to navigating between pages in my web app:

- When I use `NavigationManager.NavigateTo(uri, true)`, I am unable to open links using my scroll click (which would open the link in a new browser tab if I were to use `href="uri"` instead). It opens a new tab, but loads the same page I was already on.
- When I use `href="uri"` instead, the scroll-click works. However, it introduces a new problem: with a 'normal' left-click, the new page loads but retains the scroll position of the previous page in a mobile browser (I have tested with mobile Safari, as well as the mobile emulator in Chrome).

I need to be able to scroll-click into a new tab, as well as have a new page load without retaining the previous page's scroll position. Any tips?

Comment: There is no feature in Blazor that allows us to scroll to a certain point on the page. Scrolling to a specific location on a web page is currently only possible through JavaScript. You can refer to this post：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55186784/scroll-to-specified-part-of-page-when-clicking-top-navigation-link-in-blazor

Comment: @NMSL you misunderstood the question. I am not looking for the ability to scroll to a certain point on the page. I would explain what I'm trying to do in this comment, but I would just be repeating what I wrote in the OP.

Comment: What you describe with the left click and scroll position does not happen in an out-of-the-box new project. Perhaps you introduced the scroll position problem with something you added to the project. Can you create a small public repro of the problem?

Comment: @MisterMagoo just to be clear - are you testing this using Desktop Chrome's iPhone emulator? That (and on iPhone devices) is where I'm seeing the scroll position behavior.

Comment: Yes, I have tried using Desktop Chrome iphone mode - do you have a custom navmenu? are you using any JS? Have you tried your test with a brand new project?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the `onclick` event:
The `onclick` event does not listen for the scroll wheel click. To fix this just use the `onmousedown` event instead:

```
<button class="btn btn-dark" @onmousedown="OnClick">Test</button>

@code {

    private void OnClick()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/counter", true);
    }

}
```